# question about calculus and the derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $F$ is continously differentiable on some open set $U \subset R^2$. Why does it follow that we can write

$$ F(x+ \alpha, y + \beta) - F(x,y) = \frac{ \partial F}{\partial x} \cdot \alpha + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\cdot \beta + |H| g(H)$$

where $g(H) \to 0 $ and $|H| \to 0 $ and $H = ( \alpha, \beta )$

??

Comment: Do you mean to ask "that we CAN write"? Check the definition of differentiability (you can relax the class $C^1$ requirement, it's not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

By definition of differentiability, we have that
$$
F(x+h,y+k) = F(x,y) + h \partial_1 F(x,y) + k \partial_2 F(x,y) + o(\|(h,k)\|)
$$
as $\|(h,k)\| \to 0$. Hence $$g(h,k)=\frac{o(\|(h,k)\|)}{\|(h,k)\|} \to 0.$$